# External hard drive making clicking noises after opening case

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I've been using a Western Digital elements 2TB external USB 3.0 drive for half a year now, and it always worked fine, until yesterday. I don't know why, but it just stopped working, instead of spinning up, the drive would just make some **buzzing noise**. I recognized this as the head stuck on the platter so I opened the drive to confirm. I **moved the head back to its resting position**, and closed the drive.

Now I can hear the motor spin up as it normally would, but the drive still doesn't get detected on my computer. Instead, it makes **clicking noises** about twice a second [click here for a sample](https://soundcloud.com/droggelbecher956/broken-hard-disk-clicking).

I think this might be the head continously switching on and off the platter. Any ideas how to fix this? Could it be caused by a defect circuit board?

Comment: The minute you opened the drive in a normal environment was the same minute you made any solution to your problem impossible to implement.  The fact it's clicking tells me the mechanics are NOT working

Comment: @Ramhound What would have been your solution if I had not opened the drive? So I know for the next time...
Furthermore, I stumbled upon some post where this symptom was traced back to a damaged circuit board. Couldn't this also be the case?

Comment: There is no one-size fits all solution.  Gently dropping the drive can provide a short-term fix, freezing the drive can sometimes work as well.  Once you open the drive (in a non-cleanroom environment) you are going to greatly reduce the amount of data you can recover even if you can fix the problem - The answer for next time is the same as always - keep backups and restore from them.  If your data is worth a lot, go to a recovery specialist.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq - I appreciate your feedback and will take it into advisement.

Comment: @LukeLR - Due to you contaminating your HDD by opening it up, any advice or information I have, cannot be performed.  So I simply cannot help you.  I wish you luck.

Comment: You're all telling me that opening the disk was dumb and makes any recovery impossible. That's fine, and although I've fixed several hard disk with stuck heads exactly the same way before (and the data was still accessible), I accept your opinion. But why don't you just tell me what I could have done if I hadn't open the drive, so I (or others) know what's the better way? And besides that, I am not talking about the data, I just want to know why the head doesn't stick to the platter but always jumps back.

Comment: Despite the superficial differences, this sounds very much like a duplicate of [After upgrading to Windows 8, hard disk sporadically does not work; what's wrong?](http://superuser.com/q/628049/53590)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I don't think it's a duplicate, because that person reports his drive stops after several seconds. Mine keeps spinning, only the head is flipping on and off. I think that's a difference.

Comment: @LukeLR It isn't so much a duplicate because of the exact symptoms, but because of the attempted fix and subsequent current state. Both current answers to that question are perfectly valid answers to your question of what to do after you did what you did.

Comment: Again, this is not about the data and that it gets damaged if it's exposed to dust, my question is: Why is the head constantly jumping on and off the platter? Might this be a defect on the circuit board?

Comment: Click of death means the read head cannot read positioning data, which is the first step when the drive powers up, the drive is toast unless you want to spend a lot of money with a professional service to recover data. Either the read head is defective or a chip on the pcb board has malfunctioned. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbq8vfs1wYY

Comment: @Moab Thanks! That's a helpful reply. So the head starts up, doesn't know where to go, and jumps back for another try? Might buying a new controller PCB for my disk be a *possible* solution?

Comment: @LukeLR No you opened the drive in a non clean room and destroyed it.

Comment: Like I said earlier (yay for mods deleting my posts), opening the drive does NOT make recovery impossible. Most hard drives will work just fine with the cover off entirely. But again as I stated earlier, your problem is most likely damaged heads. To fix anything you have to determine what caused the heads to seize in the first place, and also whether the heads themselves are damaged (which IMO, they probably are).

Comment: @Moab: Opening a drive in a non clean room does not destroy it. It's certainly no good for the drive but there's no magical self-destruct that triggers when you take the lid off. I've disassembled a good dozen or so drives both with and without filtered air facilities. Hell, I ran two drives with the lid off sitting on my office desk for a few hours for fun. Final result? 8 bad sectors on the drive (4 of which were there before I disassembled it).

Comment: The higher the platter density the faster the microscopic dust you let in will destroy the drive, Yes you could do what you did with older drives, try it with a modern high capacity drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, when a drive is clicking, that is signalling the end of the drive.  If the drive was under warranty, I would have suggested sending it back for replacement.  However, since you physically *opened* the drive, you voided the warranty.  Drives are sealed for many reasons, such as preventing dust from getting in and a consistent air pressure and flow and the correct humidity level.

As for fixing it, well...  There isnt a lot you can do.  There are many known methods that can temporarily fix a drive in that state.  Freezing a drive has been known to temporarily fix drives in that condition.  The same goes for dropping it (the shock can free a stuck actuator arm).  However, these are temporary fixes at best.  They can also damage the drive further, even destroying it.

Again, this drive is essentially dead.  If the data on the drive is valuable, I would take it to a data recovery specialist ASAP.

Comment: The drive is also almost certainly full of dust by now. At the tolerances that rotational HDDs operate at, even small dust particles are HUGE, let alone what almost certainly happened when the OP moved the read/write head, *which was stuck to the platter*, away from the platter *manually*. The odds of any significant amounts of data being recoverable from this drive are probably nonexistent, and I'd say the odds of *any* data being recoverable at this point are slim at best.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Well, it cant hurt to try to take it to a data recovery shop.  The worst that can happen is they say it is unreadable.

Comment: And likely send you a fairly hefty bill for the privilege. But yes, in principle I agree. And I definitely agree with the general gist that HDDs are not DIY-fixable for the vast majority of even technically inclined people.

Comment: FWIW, I looked up the numbers two years ago for my [answer here](http://superuser.com/a/628105/53590)...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling well its up to the OP to decide of the data is valuable enough to try.  Im still *shocked* he opened up the drive.

Comment: You're getting no argument from me there!

Comment: I'm surprised there's not a warning label on the drives now that says,  "Open and Peril awaits." or something similar to a "Contents are Hot" on coffee from fast food places.  My comment doesn't add anything to the question, but I felt like posting.